# java.lang.IllegalStateException : Calling [asyncDispatch()] is not valid for a request with Async state [COMPLETING]

Tags: servlets, tomcat7, java-ee-6, servlet-3.0, asynchronous

I have following Async Servlet, corresponding Listener and a AsyncProcessor class

AsyncProcessor.java :

```
public class AsyncProcessor implements Runnable {

    private AsyncContext asyncContext;

    public AsyncProcessor(AsyncContext asyncContext, String view) {
        this.asyncContext = asyncContext;
        this.asyncContext.getRequest().setAttribute("dispatch", view);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10*1000);
            asyncContext.complete();
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

MyServlet13.java:

```
@WebServlet(name="myServlet13", urlPatterns="/servlet13", asyncSupported=true)
public class MyServlet13 extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync();
        System.out.println("Before starting Async processing");
        asyncContext.addListener(new MyAsyncListener());
        Executor executor = (Executor)getServletContext().getAttribute("executor");
        asyncContext.start(new AsyncProcessor(asyncContext, "/jsp13.jsp"));
        System.out.println("After starting Async processing");
    }

}
```

MyAsyncListener.java:

```
public class MyAsyncListener implements AsyncListener {

    public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("This is from onStartAsync");
    }

    public void onComplete(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("This is from onComplete, before dispatch");
        AsyncContext asyncContext = asyncEvent.getAsyncContext();
        asyncContext.dispatch("/jsp13.jsp");
        asyncContext.getResponse().getWriter().println("Async tasks completed...<br>");
        System.out.println("This is from onComplete, after dispatch");
    }

    public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("This is from onTimeout");
    }

    public void onError(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("This is from onError");
    }

}
```

When I try invoking `MyServlet13` with /servlet13 url pattern, I get below exception

**java.lang.IllegalStateException : Calling [asyncDispatch()] is not valid for a request with Async state [COMPLETING]**

Not sure whats wrong in this code

As per servlet3.0 spec, we are allowed to add AsyncListeners to obtained `AsyncContext`
And it will be capable of listening various events. In my case, `onComplete()` should be listened and the request should be dispatched to `jsp13.jsp` view (I do have `jsp13.jsp` in my web app context)

I'm using latest version of tomcat 7.0.x and servlet 3.0 spec

Comment: Interesting thing is, sometimes I get above error and sometimes a blank page<br>

FYI, the onComplete() of AsyncListener is invoked and I'm able to see "This is from onComplete, after dispatch" on server console

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't gonna work. You already completed your request, you can't dispatch it again. complete() ends your cycle, response has been sent.